# RxJava FlatMap: How to skip errors?

Tags: java, rx-java

In chain `obs1.flatmap(x -> obs2()).subscribe(sub)` if `obs2` produces an error, it causes immediate calling `onError` on `sub`. This is as documented:

> Note that if any of the individual Observables mapped to the items
>   from the source Observable by flatMap aborts by invoking onError, the
>   Observable produced by flatMap will itself immediately abort and
>   invoke onError.

But is it possible to ignore `obs2` errors and make `obs1` continue emitting?

Answer (score 11):

Rx provide some operators to deals with errors. Just create a third Observable from obs2 that doesn't propagate error.

```
Observable<YourType> obs3 = obs2.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.<YourType>empty());
obs1.flatmap(x -> obs3)
```

Comment: And it can be inlined:
`obs1.flatMap(x -> obs2.onErrorResumeNext(Observable.empty()))`

Comment: But what if can keep eceiving next values from source?

Comment: I didn't get your question. Maybe it's a good candidate for a separate one ?

Answer (score 4):

`.onErrorResumeNext` - you can use this to try to handle it differently, this way you will pass the previously emitted value, which when handled produced an error to another observable where you can try another approach. Or handle the error case.

`.onErrorReturn` - If it is ok for you, just return some default value and ignore the error.

Answer (score -2):

Couldn't you just make a big try-catch blog inside `obs2()` and leave the catch blog empty? No Errors will be thrown and therefore, `onError` of `sub` won't be called, will it?